# Como "contornar" o Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded no php?

Tags: php, foreach, timeout

Tenho um script que importa os imóveis de uma imobiliária por um xml.

Quando há muitos imóveis, ele dá timeout após 30 segundos (Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded).

Há alguma forma de eu contornar isso? Abaixo meu código resumido e uma alternativa que tentei, mas não deu certo.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("/arquivo.xml");
foreach($xml->children()->children() as $i){
    //PEGA OS DADDOS DO XML
    //PEGA FOTOS E REDIMENSIONA
    //INSERE NO BANCO DE DADOS
}
```

Aí tentei fazer ele atualizar de um em um, atualizando a pág.

Ele primeiro insere todos os imoveis em um banco dedados chamado "IMPORTAR". Aí pega o ultimo, puxa os dados importa e exclui desse banco, e assim seguidamente até terminar.

```
//FAZ CONSULTA MYSQL BUSCA QUAIS IMOVEIS PARA IMPORTAR PEGANDO APENAS O ULTIMO
$xml = simplexml_load_file("/arquivo.xml");
foreach($xml->children()->children() as $i){
    if($i->id_xml==$id_consulta){
        //PEGA OS DADDOS DO XML
        //PEGA FOTOS E REDIMENSIONA
        //INSERE NO BANCO DE DADOS

        //EXCLUI ESSE IMÓVEL DO BANCO DE DADOS "IMPORTAR"
    }
}
```

Dessa forma ele ficou mais tempo, mas depois de um tempo ele também trava.

Comment: Da uma olhada https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: O que demora mais tempo nas tarefas que você está executando? já tentou avaliar em qual parte ele demora mais e isolar isso? Meu palpite é no download e redimensionamento das imagens. Você pode adotar uma abordagem de executar esse processo fora de fluxo através de uma fila ou mensageria.

Comment: Bem, eu entendi que você atualiza a página a cada registro inserido. Correto? Se for isso recomendo a inserção em bloco. Como tá a regra para insert do seu script?

Comment: `<code>
protected function inserir(array $ins):
    {
        try {
            $col = implode(", ", array_keys($ins));
            $val = ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($ins));
            $stmt = Connect::getInstance()->prepare("INSERT INTO {$this->entity} ({$col}) VALUES ({$val})");
            $stmt->execute($this->filter($ins));
            return Connect::getInstance()->lastInsertId();
        } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            $this->fail = $exception;
            return null;
        }
    }
</code>`

Answer (score -1):

Olá, você pode realizar a alteração desta variável indo no arquivo *php.ini* e procurando por `max_execution_time;`

Exemplo:

```
max_execution_time = 60 # o tempo será alterado para 60 segundos.
```

Comment: Mas e se ele precisar tratar um outro arquivo com o dobro de imóveis? É de se esperar que a complexidade seja ao menos linear, então se dobrou a entrada, pelo menos se dobra o tempo de processamento

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia! não se gosta de trabalhar com arrays
Eu particularmente gosto e acredito que seria uma opção

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('integracao.xml');
$xmlArray = json_encode($xml, true);
$xmlArray = json_decode($xmlArray, true);

/*
Depois que estiver com o conteudo do xml em um array
Nesse momento usamos a implementação do php ArrayObject que tem inumeros 
recursos para trabalhar com array e melhorando a performance
*/

$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($xmlArray);
/*
Aqui nesseo ponto como estamos usando ArrayObject podemos usar o recurso de 
iterator
*/
$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

print "<pre>";
while ($iterator->valid()) {
  echo $iterator->key() . ' = ' . print_r($iterator->current()) . "\n";
  $iterator->next();
}
```

E depois o while vai funcionar como o foreach onde iterator->key é a chave e iterator->current é o conteudo

Esse processo ajuda na performace e memória pode ser uma opção

Comment: converter para array vai garantir que não aconteça o timeout?

Comment: não!  apenas pensei em uma alternativa para tentar reduzir o tempo de processamento.
pois fiz alguns testes e aparentemente processou mais rápido.